# SQL left Join with DISTINCT ON returns duplicate rows

Tags: database, postgresql, distinct, mikro-orm, distinct-on

I`m using node with mikro-orm v5 and postgres 14.
My schema goes like this:

```
- Business
  - Addresses[]
  - Sectors[]
```

And I want to query the addresses by distance.

The problem is that the return is two addresses with the same ID, one for each sector. If I remove the `sector.id` from the DISTINCT ON it returns one address but only one sector.

How can I return one address and two sectors?

My code:

```js
const addressRepo = em.getRepository(Address);
const distanceQuery = addressRepo.buildDistanceQuery({ latitude, longitude });

const businessName = businessNameRaw?.trim();

// Start query
const qb = em.createQueryBuilder(Address, 'address');

const distinctOnColumns = [
  businessName ? `LEVENSHTEIN(business.business_name, '${businessName}')` : undefined,
  'distance',
  ...(data.orderBy ?? []),
  'sector.id',
  'address.id',
].filter((e) => !!e);

// Must match DISTINCT ON columns order
let orderBy: QBQueryOrderMap<Address> = {
  businessName: QueryOrder.ASC,
  distance: QueryOrder.ASC,
  ...data.orderBy?.reduce((obj, each, index) => ({ ...obj, [each]: data.orderDirection?.[index] }), {}),
  [qb.raw<string>('sector.id')]: QueryOrder.ASC,
  id: QueryOrder.ASC,
};

await qb
  .select([
    qb.raw(`distinct on(${distinctOnColumns.join(', ')}) address.*`),
    qb.raw(`${distanceQuery} as distance`),
  ])
  .leftJoinAndSelect('address.business', 'business')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('business.account', 'account')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('business.sectors', 'sector')

const total =
  (
    await qb
      .clone()
      .select('count(distinct(address.id)) as total')
      .andWhere(`${distanceQuery} < ?`, [distance])
      .execute('get')
  ).total || 0;

await qb
  .having(`${distanceQuery} < ?`, [distance])
  .groupBy([
    'address.id',
    'business.id',
    'account.id',
    'sector.id',
  ])
  .orderBy(orderBy)
  .limit(perPage, offset);

const results = await qb.execute<Address[]>('all');
```

The query from the code above:

```sql
select
  distinct on(
    LEVENSHTEIN(
      business.business_name,
      'Moraes, Macedo and Barros'
    ),
    distance,
    sector.id
  ) address.*,
  ROUND(
    CAST(
      (
        6371 * 2 * ASIN(
          SQRT(
            POWER(
              SIN(
                (-22.896547 - "address"."latitude") * pi() / 180 / 2
              ),
              2
            ) + COS(-22.896547 * pi() / 180) * COS("address"."latitude" * pi() / 180) * POWER(
              SIN(
                (-43.18179 - "address"."longitude") * pi() / 180 / 2
              ),
              2
            )
          )
        )
      ) AS numeric
    ),
    20
  ) as distance,
  "business"."id" as "business__id",
  "business"."updated_at" as "business__updated_at",
  "business"."created_at" as "business__created_at",
  "business"."business_name" as "business__business_name",
  "business"."description" as "business__description",
  "business"."first_name" as "business__first_name",
  "business"."last_name" as "business__last_name",
  "business"."cpf" as "business__cpf",
  "business"."birth_day" as "business__birth_day",
  "business"."employees" as "business__employees",
  "business"."account_id" as "business__account_id",
  "account"."id" as "account__id",
  "account"."updated_at" as "account__updated_at",
  "account"."created_at" as "account__created_at",
  "account"."email" as "account__email",
  "account"."cellphone_number" as "account__cellphone_number",
  "account"."is2faenabled" as "account__is2faenabled",
  "account"."password_change_expires" as "account__password_change_expires",
  "account"."picture_uri" as "account__picture_uri",
  "account"."last_sign_in_at" as "account__last_sign_in_at",
  "account"."last_access_at" as "account__last_access_at",
  "account"."client_id" as "account__client_id",
  "account"."business_id" as "account__business_id",
  "sector"."id" as "sector__id",
  "sector"."updated_at" as "sector__updated_at",
  "sector"."created_at" as "sector__created_at",
  "sector"."name" as "sector__name",
  "sector"."icon" as "sector__icon",
from
  "address" as "address"
  left join "business" as "business" on "address"."business_id" = "business"."id"
  left join "account" as "account" on "business"."account_id" = "account"."id"
  left join "sector_businesses" as "s1" on "business"."id" = "s1"."business_id"
  left join "sector" as "sector" on "s1"."sector_id" = "sector"."id"
where
  (
    unaccent(business.business_name) ILIKE unaccent('%Moraes, Macedo and Barros%')
  )
group by
  "address"."id",
  "business"."id",
  "account"."id",
  "sector"."id",
  "business"."business_name"
having
  (
    ROUND(
      CAST(
        (
          6371 * 2 * ASIN(
            SQRT(
              POWER(
                SIN(
                  (-22.896547 - "address"."latitude") * pi() / 180 / 2
                ),
                2
              ) + COS(-22.896547 * pi() / 180) * COS("address"."latitude" * pi() / 180) * POWER(
                SIN(
                  (-43.18179 - "address"."longitude") * pi() / 180 / 2
                ),
                2
              )
            )
          )
        ) AS numeric
      ),
      20
    ) < 60000
  )
order by
  LEVENSHTEIN(
    business.business_name,
    'Moraes, Macedo and Barros'
  ) asc,
  "distance" asc,
  "sector"."id" asc
limit
  100
```

And the return. The address returns twice because the sectors has two rows.

```json
{
  "results": [
    {
      "id": "96d13133-a224-44df-b96c-ea938c1bfd6a",
      "line1": "2349 Beatriz Alameda",
      "line2": null,
      "district": "Cambridgeshire",
      "city": "Detroit",
      "stateOrProvince": "ES",
      "country": "CX",
      "postalCode": "25151508",
      "latitude": 71.473,
      "longitude": 99.9465,
      "isMain": true,
      "isBilling": true,
      "distance": "14131.78452896010000000000",
      "business": {
        "id": "133c05a7-ce43-46e4-8cc6-941e889329bf",
        "sectors": [
          {
            "id": "1633946a-ca28-428c-a847-30f61667afbc",
            "name": "Depilação"
          },
          {
            "id": "51ef3ea1-5bdf-45dd-ad10-a3aa3a7a2f33",
            "name": "Cabeleireiro"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "96d13133-a224-44df-b96c-ea938c1bfd6a",
      "line1": "2349 Beatriz Alameda",
      "line2": null,
      "district": "Cambridgeshire",
      "city": "Detroit",
      "stateOrProvince": "ES",
      "country": "CX",
      "postalCode": "25151508",
      "latitude": 71.473,
      "longitude": 99.9465,
      "isMain": true,
      "isBilling": true,
      "distance": "14131.78452896010000000000",
      "business": {
        "id": "133c05a7-ce43-46e4-8cc6-941e889329bf",
        "sectors": [
          {
            "id": "1633946a-ca28-428c-a847-30f61667afbc",
            "name": "Depilação"
          },
          {
            "id": "51ef3ea1-5bdf-45dd-ad10-a3aa3a7a2f33",
            "name": "Cabeleireiro"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

---

*Edit 1*

Alright, changing to `qb.getResult()` worked, more or less...

The `address` results are now unique, but the `sectors` does not return properly.
It returns only one or two when there are far more.

When I add `sector.id` to DISTINCT ON it returns properly, but the `address` results does not it returns less than the amount specified by the `limit()`... but the `count` returns the right amount.

---

*Edit 2*

I tried reproducing my errors and found some others:
https://codesandbox.io/s/node-ts-mikro-orm-i4yckf?file=/src/index.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `qb.execute()`, you get the raw database results, and they will contain duplicates if you join a to-many relation (so a collection of entities - 1:m or m:n property).

This is also the reason why you see that complex query (with nested subqueries) being generated, as if you combine to-many join with a limit clause, it would not work as expected (you would not limit the root entity, as there would be duplicates).

You should prefer using `qb.getResult()` which will map the results to entities, it will handle deduplication.

Comment: Thanks @Martin, I tried changing to `qb.getResult()` and it gave me a `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` error. I'm gonna look into it.

Comment: Cant help you with just error messages. At least provide the full stack trace, but usually a reproduction is needed for such things.

Comment: Hey! I was able to fix the error that I mentioned above, but now I have another that I added to the post.